# Displaying "Download Image" caption on popup image

Tags: javascript, html

At the moment the javascript code below is used to display a caption on an image popup

```
if ($(obj).attr("title") != "") {
$("<span class=\"caption\">" + $(obj).attr("title") + "</span>").appendTo("#" + _17.popupId + "_content").hide();}
```

I need for it to display "download image" instead of the current output which is:

`<span class="caption">Title</span>`

how do I convert the following javascript code into displaying the below output:

`<a href="rel" download>Download image</a>`

I've tried the following and had no luck

```
if ($(obj).attr("title") != "") {
                  $("<a class=\"caption\" href=\"#\" download="rel">" + $(obj).attr("title") + "</a>").appendTo("#" + _17.popupId + "_content").hide();
               }
```

Comment: so you basically need to replace a tag with span ?

Comment: need to replace the span with the href download tag basically but i'm doing something wrong as I'm not that good in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I think you messed up the quoting of the download attribute (" vs. \"). I would change to single quotes to contain the string, it will be much easier to read:

```
if ($(obj).attr("title") != "") {
    $('<a class="caption" href="#" download="rel">' + $(obj).attr("title") + '</a>').appendTo("#" + _17.popupId + "_content").hide();
}
```

Comment: it is correct to escape double quotes with a backslash and it produces the formally more readable html. The only issue in OP code is that it miss a couple of escaping

Comment: That's what I meant. The resulting HTML still uses double quotes in my example.

Answer (score 0):

every time you put a double quote that should be considered as part of the string and not evaluated by js you need to escape it with a backslash.

That's why you have `href=\"#\"` and you should also have `download=\"rel\"` if rel is a string.

If rel is a js variable then: `download=\""+rel+"\"` to perform the string concatenation